# Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate with onconfiguring dbcontext options

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an application I am trying to run. The server path has been created but I application still gives me the following error

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'DbService.PetLicensingContext' while attempting to activate 'DbService.Controllers.BreedController'.

Here is my  Context

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DbService
{
    public class PetLicensingContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Breed> Breeds { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pet> Pets { get; set; }

        public string DbPath { get; }

        public PetLicensingContext()
        {
            var folder = Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData;
            var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(folder);
            DbPath = System.IO.Path.Join(path, "petlicensing.db");
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
            => options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}");        
    }
}
```

This is my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DbService.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class BreedController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<BreedController> _logger;
        private readonly PetLicensingContext _context;

        public BreedController(ILogger<BreedController> logger, PetLicensingContext context)
        {

            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("all")]
        public IActionResult GetAllBreeds()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting all breeds");
            var breeds = _context.Owners;
            return Ok(breeds);
        }
}
}
```

Would I have to configure the connection as a service? If so can someone please provide an example.

Thanks!

Comment: U need to register your DbContext at startup
`services.AddDbContext<PetLicensingContext>(builder =>
{
.....
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem!

In this Startup.cs I added this service

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<PetLicensingContext>();
```